# Binary Search Tree delete function not working properly

Tags: c++, tree, binary-search-tree

I am working with a binary search tree and am attempting to create a function to delete a single node. For some reason certain nodes will not delete (most of the seem to be instances that have a right node but not a left) but exactly what node won't delete seems pretty haphazard which makes it difficult to debug. Occasionally I will get the error

`mov(30071,0x7fff73b1d300) malloc: *** error for object 0x7fcb2b404f40: pointer being freed was not allocated
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
Abort trap: 6`

but most of the time the node just doesn't delete and the program continues to run.

Here is my delete function:

```
Node* Tree::deleteNode(Node *node,string title)
{
if(node == NULL){
  return node;
}
else if(node->title.compare(title) > 0){
  node->left = deleteNode(node->left, title);
} 
else if(node->title.compare(title) < 0){
  node->right = deleteNode(node->right, title);
} 
else 
{
  //No Child
     if(node->left == NULL && node->right == NULL){
        if(node == node->parent->right)
        {
            node->parent->right = NULL;
        }
        else
        {
            node->parent->left = NULL;
        }
        node = NULL;
     }
     //One child
     else if(node->left == NULL)
     {
       //Here is where some fail
       Node *temp = node;
       node = node->right;
       delete temp;
     } 
     else if(node->right == NULL)
     {
       Node *temp = node;
       node = node->left;
       delete temp;
     } 
     else
     {
       Node *temp = treeMinimum(node->right);
       node->title = temp->title;
       node->right = deleteNode(node->right, temp->title);
     }
  }
 return node;
}
```

and:

```
Node* Tree::treeMinimum(Node *node)
{
    while(node->left != NULL)
    {
        node = node->left;
    }
    return node;
}
```

It is always the same Nodes that won't delete but other nodes that are the  same structurally (no left node, yes right node) delete no problem. The program always starts with the same tree of 50 nodes. I apologize if this information isn't suffice, please let me know if there is anything else I can provide. Thank you

Comment: I don't immediately see a memory corruption problem. You should run this code through a static analysis tool, such as valgrind. The bug probably likely lies somewhere else. I suspect that somewhere else you are probably corrupting the heap, and you hit it when you delete the tree. I do see an obvious memory leak, though. "if(node->left == NULL && node->right == NULL)", then you fail to delete the discarded node.